# A continuously differentiable function $f$ Satisfying $ \| f ( x ) - f ( y ) \| \geq \| x - y \| , \forall x , y \in \mathbb { R } ^ { n } $ is onto

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, frechet-derivative

Let $f: \mathbb { R^n } \rightarrow \mathbb { R } ^ { n }$ be continuously
differentiable, Satisfying
$$
\| f ( x ) - f ( y ) \| \geqslant \| x - y \| , \forall x , y \in \mathbb { R } ^ { n }
$$
then how to prove that $f$ is onto.

My work:
Consider $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow Range(f),$ 
Then clearly $f$ is bijective
from $\mathbb { R } ^ { n }$ onto  $Range( f )$
also since $$\left\| f ^ { - 1 } ( x ) -f ^ { - l } ( y ) \right\| \leq \| x - y \|$$
$f ^ { - 1 }: \operatorname { Range } (f) \rightarrow \operatorname {\mathbb R^n }$
Continuous.
Thus $Range(f) \subseteq \mathbb { R } ^ { n }$ is
homeomorphic to $\mathbb { R } ^ { n }$,
is the way is correct? I am not getting idea further.

Comment: How exactly did you conclude that the range of $f$ is $\mathbb R^n$ from the fact that $f\simeq\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: It cannot always be true. For example consider $\operatorname{ln}:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$. It is continuous and has continuous inverse $\operatorname{exp}$ so that $(0,\infty)\simeq\mathbb R$ but they are not equal.

Comment: If $f$ weren't surjective, there'd be a $z \in \overline{f(\mathbb{R}^n)}\setminus f(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Try to obtain a contradiction from that.

Comment: if the statement to be proved is true I would try a proof by contradiction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For suppose $z\in\overline{f(\mathbb{R}^{n})}-f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, there is a sequence $(w_{n})$ such that $f(w_{n})\rightarrow z$. But then $\|f(w_{n})-f(w_{m})\|\geq\|w_{n}-w_{m}\|$, so $(w_{n})$ is Cauchy and hence convergent, say, $w_{n}\rightarrow w$. Continuity gives $f(w_{n})\rightarrow f(w)$ and hence $z=f(w)\in f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, a contradiction.

This shows that $f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is closed.

We claim that $f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is open, for then $f(\mathbb{R}^{n})=\mathbb{R}^{n}$ by the connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

The Jacobian is not singular, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043136/if-f-u-rightarrow-mathbbrn-differentiable-such-that-fx-fy-geq-c). Hence Inverse Function Theorem gives you that $f$ is an open map, so $f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is open.

Comment: This shows that $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is closed. I think you need more to deduce that $f(\mathbb{R}^n)=\mathbb{R}^n$, e.g. the fact that it is open as well.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I think now it works.

Comment: If $g:f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is continuous, then $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^{n}$-$f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ open, this is relatively. But we don't know yet $f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is itself open or not.

Comment: How can you say that Jacobian is non- singular? You got the sum of squares of absolute values of derivatives $\geq 1$, from that?

Comment: If the Jacobian is the zero matrix, then each of its component is zero, so all the partials are zeros, then it is not possible for the sum of any of the row of those partials to be greater than one

Comment: Ya......its clear that Jacobian is non-zero, but i am not getting how it is non- singular...

Comment: I see your point now, I messed up with nonzero and nonsingular, sorry, I will try to repair my proof.

Comment: I found a useful link to show that why it is non-singular, sorry for messed up.

Answer (score 1):

We show the image is open and closed. Since it's also nonempty, by connectedness of  ${\mathbb R}^n$ it's all of ${\mathbb R}^n$:

Openness: This will follow from the inverse function theorem if we can show the matrix $Df(x_0)$ is nonsingular at each $x_0$; the range of $f$ is the union of the open sets that are the images of the open sets provided by the inverse function theorem.

Note that we have
$$f(x) = f(x_0) + Df(x_0)(x-x_0) + o(x- x_0)$$
If $v$ is any vector of magnitude $1$, if we let $x = x_0 + tv$ for $0 < t < 1$, the above gives
$$f(x_0 + tv) - f(x_0) = tDf(x_0)v + o(t)$$
This implies
$${|f(x_0 + tv) - f(x_0)| \over t} = Df(x_0)v + o(1)$$
Since by assumption $|f(x_0 + tv) - f(x_0)| > t$, letting $t$ go to zero 
we get that $Df(x_0)v $ is nonzero for any vector $v$. Thus the matrix $Df(x_0)$ is nonsingular for all $x_0$ and the image of $f$ is open.

Closedness: Suppose $y_n$ are in the range of $f$ and $\lim_n y_n = y_0$ for some $y_0$. Let $x_n$ be such that $f(x_n) = y_n$. Since the 
$y_n$ converge, the $y_n$ are a Cauchy sequence. By assumption, $|x_n - x_m| \leq |f(x_n) - f(x_m)| = |y_n - y_m|$. Hence the $x_n$ are a Cauchy sequence too and converge to some $x_0$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$. By continuity $f(x_0) = y_0$ and hence $y_0$ is in the range of $f$. We conclude the range of $f$ is closed.

Comment: Can we use the continuity of the inverse $f^{-1}$ from $f(\mathbb R^n)$ to $\mathbb R^n$ to say that $f(\mathbb R^n)$ is open?

Comment: No, that would just say that the image $f(U)$ for any open $U$ is open in the relative topology on $f({\mathbb R}^n)$. In other words, $f(U) \cap f({\mathbb R}^n)$ is open.